# Drupal10, Drush not cleared

Tags: drupal, drush, drupal-10

Doesn't implement drush, doesn't clear the cache, although it says everything is fine.

`root@p656470:~# sudo -u www drush cr -vvv`

`[preflight] Config paths: /www/wwwroot/site.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml`

`[preflight] Alias paths: /www/wwwroot/site.com/web/drush/sites,/www/wwwroot/site.com/drush/sites`

`[preflight] Commandfile search paths: /www/wwwroot/site.com/vendor/drush/drush/src`

`[info] Starting bootstrap to site [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Drush bootstrap phase 2 [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2 [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Change working directory to /www/wwwroot/site.com/web [0.07 sec, 7.78 MB]`

`[info] Initialized Drupal 10.1.6 root directory at /www/wwwroot/site.com/web [0.08 sec, 7.83 MB]`

`[info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.08 sec, 7.83 MB]`

`[info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2 [0.08 sec, 8.28 MB]`

`[info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.08 sec, 8.28 MB]`

`[debug] Could not find a Drush config file at sites/default/drush.yml. [0.08 sec, 8.44 MB]`

`[info] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.08 sec, 8.44 MB]`

`[success] Cache rebuild complete. [1.72 sec, 63.8 MB]`

For example, if you make changes to the template, then after drush cr, the changes are not visible only if you reset the cache from the admin panel. What could be wrong?

Comment: What does "only if you reset the cache from the admin panel" mean? Server admin panel? Then it's probably server side caching and has nothing to do with Drupal.

Comment: here /admin/config/development/performance

Comment: looks like drush cr is not working properly. why are you switching user and running drush cr. you can just run drush cr in the drupal root folder. try sudo -u www | drush cr